# Can I pipe files from find to less?

Tags: shell, pipe

I have a bunch of files, and need to examine all which are non-empty. I can find these files e.g. by running

```
find *e* -maxdepth 1 -size +0 -print
```

But if I add `| less` to the above, I only get to see the list of files, not the files themselves.

If I manually give this filelist as an argument to **less** (`less file1.e file2.e file3.e` etc.) I get what I want, but this kind of cumbersome. Is there any way I can pipe the output of **find** to **less** directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run `less` on each file in turn:

```
find *e* -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +0 -exec less {} \;
```

or:

```
find *e* -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +0 | xargs less
```

to run `less` on the entire list (assuming the number of files is not huge - xargs limits max no of arguments to 5000 typically).

Note that addition of `-type f` so that you don't return directories from `find`.

Comment: Note that the latter may invoke `less` more than once, so is not guaranteed to present the *entire list*.

Comment: I like the former version since it allows me to jump to the next file with just `q`, instead of `:n` (which on my keyboard is three keystrokes). **Followup question:** Is there a way to kill the rest of the less-processes after I have examined e.g. 10 out of 200 files, or do I just have to keep `q` pressed until they all quit. Hiding them with Ctrl-Z seems a bit messy...

Comment: You should just be able to Control-C out, no ?

Comment: Indeed I can. I thought I had tried that, but I guess I hadn't :P Thanks again, Paul!

Comment: ... and then `:n` or `:p` to go to next or previous file.